# Need help to convert json to pojo

Tags: java, json, pojo

```
{'countryName':USA,'countryCode':+41,'phoneNo':4427564321,'campaignId':111} 
{'countryName':USA,'countryCode':+41,'phoneNo':4427564321,'campaignId':111}
```

Now I want to convert the above `JSON` into my POJO instances that maps to each part of the String. Suppose the POJO is called `userList`. Then I need to split up the `JSON` String to 2 `userListObjects`.

Comment: Show some code what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Your Pojo class will look like:

```
public class userList{

 private String countryName;
 private String countryCode;
 private Long phoneNo;
 private Integer campaignId;

 //Getters,Setters

}
```

You can also use [this_link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate pojo just by copying and pasting your json.

Comment: I think they want to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to generate the list.

```
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    String jsonData = "[{\"countryName\":\"USA\",\"countryCode\":\"+41\",\"phoneNo\":4427564321,\"campaignId\":111},{\"countryName\":\"USA\",\"countryCode\":\"+41\",\"phoneNo\":4427564321,\"campaignId\":111}]";
    JsonElement parsedJsonElement = jsonParser.parse(jsonData);
    if(parsedJsonElement.isJsonArray()){
        JsonArray parsedJsonArray =  parsedJsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for(JsonElement jsonElement : parsedJsonArray){
            String countryName = "";
            String countryCode = "";
            long phoneNo = 0;
            int campaignId = 0;
            Iterator<Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, JsonElement> next = iterator.next();
                String key = next.getKey();
                if(key.equals("countryName")){
                    countryName = next.getValue().getAsString();
                }else if(key.equals("countryCode")){
                    countryCode = next.getValue().getAsString();
                }else if(key.equals("phoneNo")){
                    phoneNo = next.getValue().getAsLong();
                }else if(key.equals("campaignId")){
                    phoneNo = next.getValue().getAsInt();
                }
            }
            userList.add(new User(countryName, countryCode, phoneNo, campaignId));
        }
    }


        public class User {
            String countryName;
            String countryCode;
            long phoneNo;
            int campaignId;
            public User(String countryName, String countryCode, long phoneNo, int campaignId) {
                super();
                this.countryName = countryName;
                this.countryCode = countryCode;
                this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
                this.campaignId = campaignId;
            }

        }
```